# magento 2 remove .html from URL through .htaccess

Tags: magento2

```
Now is: www.example.de/cool-shoes.html
Will be: www.example.de/cool-shoes

I want to remove .htmlfrom URL through .htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from stores->configuration->catalog->search engine optimization. there are 2 suffix fields. one for category and one for product. make them empty and rebuild the indexes.

Comment: I don't want to do through configuration. I want to do it through .htaccess file